# How to secure database without authentication?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating an Unity game where I want to have global top 50 score list with usernames. I use Firebase realtime database. There is no need for user to authenticate. I am not that familiar with database security and pretty beginner with this concept. I am using Rest Api from Unity Asset store because it was pretty easy to send and get data from databse.

How can I be sure that every score sent to database is from my app?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I allow my Unity app access to a Firebase realtime Database without user accounts and without public access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54099442/how-can-i-allow-my-unity-app-access-to-a-firebase-realtime-database-without-user)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add a dedicated user with password to your database
2. Somewhere in you app, add those credentials e.g. in a ScriptableObject / in some component
3. Always use those credentials to authenticate

Note that your app can still be decompiled and thereby cheated.

You can at least make it more difficult by encrypting the data etc.

The only way really around is to have an account and sessioning server to assure a user is locked in with a valid session.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use Firebase Authentication, you can't restrict who can access your database.  Anyone will be able to issues a query, and they can even do it using the [Realtime Database REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/).  All they have to know is the name of your project.

Even if you do use Firebase Authentication, anyone may still effectively authenticate and access the database outside of your app using other public APIs.

Comment: How should I implement my database then so that I can be sure that every score is legit?

Comment: It's not about database design.  It's about making sure that your server side controls all logic should be secure.  Fact of the matter is that you can't trust the client app at all, as it may be compromised.  So, if your scoring logic is calculated on the client, it's hackable, and that's that.

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that you can't stop dedicated "users" from cheating global at high scores. I made a small handfull of trivial games for windows phone with global top 50.  Even if your game is unpopular, and you obfuscate your code, and you are on an unpopular platform, and you encrypt your network traffic: somebody is going to jailbreak their phone, decompile your app, and inject their own high score into your game before high scores are sent to the global list.  The only way I ever came up with to combat this was to keep track of play sessions -on the server- to make sure their scores were theoretically possible based on how long they were playing.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I don't know anything about Firebase

From what I can tell, you will need to set up access for `Default` and `Public` sections of your configuration to tell the database who can and cannot access your database. Here's their documentation on [Get Started with Database Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart#sample-rules).

In general database access, no one should know the details of your connection to a database, so all calls should only ever come from your app.